# couldn't determine visual studio generator

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, rust, clion

I am trying to compile rust's [azul](https://github.com/maps4print/azul) gui framework sample code on windows 10 and it's running into the following error:

```
    error: failed to run custom build command for `harfbuzz-sys v0.3.0 (https://github.com/maps4print/azul-dependencies?rev=bf2933b9aac43a7003278862772250398e4fa457#bf2933b9)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `F:\Code\rust\azul_demo\target\debug\build\harfbuzz-sys-4d7deefbb1bf663c\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HARFBUZZ_SYS_NO_PKG_CONFIG

--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at '

couldn't determine visual studio generator
if VisualStudio is installed, however, consider running the appropriate vcvars script before building this crate
', C:\Users\Andrew\.cargo\git\checkouts\azul-dependencies-70bb1f94316762f9\bf2933b\cmake-0.1.35\src\lib.rs:687:25
stack backtrace:
   0: backtrace::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized
             at C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\backtrace-0.3.29\src\backtrace\mod.rs:66
...
```

I installed cmake and visual studio 2019. Also note that I am using clion ide. Cmake version is `3.15.2`.

It says I should run the `appropriate vcvars script before building this crate`, what does it mean exactly?

EDIT ----
Found `vcvars.bat` in the visual studio installation folder and ran it. It's still getting the same error. 
EDIT2 ----
It looks like an incompatibility between the latest version of visualstudio(19) and cmake. Reverting to 2015 is suppose to resolve the issue. 
https://github.com/maps4print/azul/issues/203

Comment: What version of CMake are you using?

Comment: Cmake version is 3.15.2.

Comment: Ok, it could be the case, that your CMake is too old and does not yet know about the recent version of Visual Studio. But this shout not be the case for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Visual Studio, the command-line tools are *not* available from a generic command prompt. Visual Studio should have installed an entry in your start menu to start a properly configured console.

Or if you haven't started your console from this special entry, Visual Studio should also have installed a script called `vcvars.bat` somewhere in its install folder. You need to run that script before you can access the command-line tools.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, adding `cmake` helped me to solve the same error, but in a different project.
I just typed this command into the console:

```
cargo add cmake
```

and started the build process:

```
cargo build
```

Before that, I searched for the `vcvars.bat` script and ran it.